# Technical bug in counting the number of users who have viewed a question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, views

[image]

Why is the number of users who have viewed the question less than the number of users who have answered the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/views-indicator-inaccurate-shows-one-views-on-question-with-two-close-vote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to database caching where some of the information displayed (such as the number of views on a post) is stored locally rather than checking the database each time for the latest up-to-date number. It's a performance enhancement that generally works well across all sites, but this side effect is much more pronounced when the site is new with lower traffic. It will hardly be noticed once the site starts humming along.